# Finding an object with the lowest value and returning the object, not the value, with a stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I currently find the object with the lowest value like this:

```
List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
RGB colour = new RGB(5,3,7);
Location best = null;
double bestscore = 0.0;
for(Location loc : locations)
{
  if(best == null)
  {
    best = loc;
    bestscore = getScore(loc,colour, average);
  }
  else
  {
    double oscore = getScore(loc,colour, average);
    if(oscore < bestscore)
    {
      best = loc;
      bestscore = oscore;
    }
  }
}
```

where getScore is:

```
double getScore(Location loc, RGB colour, boolean average)
```

This is pretty slow considering locations usually has a few thousand entries and this loop is used a few million times in a row.

So I wanted to try and use the new parallelStream() from java 8. I made a comparator that compares getScore values.

```
Location best = locations.parallelStream().min(new ComparatorScoreDif(colour)).get();
```

Am I going in the right direction here, is this the right way to do this?

Comment: You need to call `get()` to get the value from the Optional. `Location best = locations.parallelStream().min(new ComparatorScoreDif(colour)).get();`. http://download.java.net/lambda/b78/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Comment: it compiles now, so I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Location best = locations.parallelStream().min(new ComparatorScoreDif(colour)).get();
```

That will return the actual object from the optional object. it it exists. You might call `.isPresent()` on the optional object beforehand to check this.

**Am I going in the right direction here, is this the right way to do this?**

Yes it is. By calling `.parallelStream()` you hand over the concurrency part to the JVM (*it will partition the stream into multiple substreams*)and you can focus on the actual logic that has to be executed in parallel.

See [OracleDocs - Parallelism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) for further information and some nice explainings.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using `min()` with a `Comparator` is the right approach to do this. However, you don't need to create your own comparator implementation `ComparatorScoreDif`. Instead, you can use the `Comparator.comparing` combinator function to generate a `Comparator`, given a function that derives the values to be compared.

Most examples use method references to getters on the object being compared. If `Location` had a `getScore` method, one would do this:

```
Location best = locations.parallelStream()
                         .min(Comparator.comparing(Location::getScore))
                         .get();
```

However, `getScore` isn't a method on `Location`, and it takes some additional parameters. This will require writing out a lambda expression "longhand" instead of using a method reference. The additional values can be captured from the environment:

```
Location best = locations.parallelStream()
                         .min(Comparator.comparingDouble(loc -> getScore(loc, colour, average)))
                         .get();
```

This avoids the need to write out a class to implement `Comparator`.

Comment: The unconditional .get() is problematic, as it will throw NSEE if locations is empty.

Comment: True, but following the OP's original code, one would end up writing `orElse(null)` which seems like it defeats the purpose of `Optional` there.